# Assign different RAW material into MediaPlayer by using switch statement

Tags: android, switch-statement, android-mediaplayer

i want to make my switch statement could assign different Raw item into my MediaPlayer, any good ideas ?

here is my MediaPlayer

```
final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.doa_tawaf_round_1);
    holder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mp2.isPlaying()) {
                mp2.pause();
                holder.imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.tawaf_play_btn);
            } else {
                mp2.start();
                holder.imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.tawaf_pause_btn);
                holder.secImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

and this is my Switch statement

```
    switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    if(point == 0) {
                        holder.rukunName.setText(R.string.rukun_hajar_aswad);
                        holder.duaText.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshapeSentence(context.getResources().getString(R.string.doa_permulaan_tawaf)));
                        holder.secDuaText.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshapeSentence(context.getResources().getString(R.string.doa_tawaf_pusingan_pertama)));
                        mp2.setRaw(R.raw.myRawFile); //Any idea what to use in here ?
                    } break;
                case 1: if(point == 0){
                        holder.rukunName.setText(R.string.rukun_hajar_aswad);
                        holder.duaText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.secDuaText.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshapeSentence(context.getResources().getString(R.string.doa_tawaf_pusingan_kedua)));
                        mp2.setRaw(R.raw.mySecondRawfile); // And also here 

                    }break;
    }
```

my "if" for case 0 is very long, i alraedy cut it and paste here so dont ask about my "case" or "if" statement :). Any help on the RAW input method would be good.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.myRawFile);
```

In order to play Raw media files with `MediaPlayer` you can create a media player with the raw file as the second parameter.

Your switch statement would be like:

```
switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    if(point == 0) {
                        holder.rukunName.setText(R.string.rukun_hajar_aswad);
                        holder.duaText.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshapeSentence(context.getResources().getString(R.string.doa_permulaan_tawaf)));
                        holder.secDuaText.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshapeSentence(context.getResources().getString(R.string.doa_tawaf_pusingan_pertama)));
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.myRawFile); //You got the idea now
                    } break;
                case 1: if(point == 0){
                        holder.rukunName.setText(R.string.rukun_hajar_aswad);
                        holder.duaText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.secDuaText.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshapeSentence(context.getResources().getString(R.string.doa_tawaf_pusingan_kedua)));
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.mySecondRawFile); // And now 

                    }break;
    }
```